# Yahoo transforms height into min-height

Tags: html, css, height, yahoo

I have just stumbled across the fact that Yahoo mail is transforming all height attributes into min-height. Is there a workaround for this?

```
<div style="width:55px; height:55px; overflow:hidden;">
   <img alt="user pic" src="assets/main.jpeg" width="55px" />
</div>
```

The goal of the code above is to hide the bottom part of the image if it's higher than 55px. I've tested this in hotmail and aol and it works fine. Only Yahoo seems to transform my height into min-height:

```
<div style="width:55px; min-height:55px; overflow:hidden;">
```

Comment: Can you set max-height to your height value?

Comment: I did, but it still gets transformed. Also, I just tested Gmail and it does the same thing as Yahoo.

Comment: That might be why tables are unfortunately so common for formatting html emails

Comment: agreed. I am already using tables. The height attribute, even if used on the td, still gets changed. I've tried div as a last resort and it happened that i posted the code with the div.

Comment: Have you tried taking the inline-style and moving it to normal CSS?

Comment: Have a look at this as well: http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/9_ways_to_prevent_yahoo_headaches

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't mention anything about height and it doesn't seem to have anything that might help this situation.

Answer (score 1):

direct height attribute without style works for yahoo like

```
<div height="55px" style="width:55px; overflow:hidden;">
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this:

Put `height: 55px;` in the `<style>` tag that is placed in the `<head>` or `<body>`. Yahoo! Mail will read the `height` property if it's defined in the `<style>` tag.

Gmail, as of now, supports @media queries, but it is best to put `height` in-line. Gmail no longer converts `height` to `min-height` right now, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're referring to Yahoo! Mail. As of April 2019, I've run into this issue myself and the work around is to simulate the height attribute effect that would otherwise work is to do this:

```
<br class="yahoo-br" style="display:none; line-height:50px;"/>
```

Give it a class name like `.yahoo-br` and set inline style to `display: none;`, so it doesn't display on other email clients. Put `<br/>` tags where ever height is needed in the code and add a `line-height` property and its value can be equivalent to the `height` attribute value. This will act exactly like a height attribute basically.

To target Yahoo! Mail, you can add css in your `<style>` in the `<head>` tag as so:

```
/* Yahoo! specific CSS */
br.yahoo-br { display: none; }
    @media screen yahoo {
        br.yahoo-br { display: block !important; }
}
```

More on how to target Yahoo! Mail found here: [The New Yahoo! Mail and How to Target It](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/the-new-yahoo-mail-and-how-to-target-it/)

Answer (score 0):

As of now in May-2019 the Yahoo mail still transforms inline style `height` to `min-height` so what i have found as workaround is add `max-height` also in your inline style then it will works.

in my case i have image in my html and i just want it's height to set to `30px` but **yahoo transforms the height to min-height.**

so it is becoming larger image but i want it to smaller so i have **applied `max-height` in inline style and it worked**.

see my `img` tag below i have applied `max-height` in inline style.

```
<img src="<?php echo $url->assets ?>img/checked.png" style="height:30px;float: left;max-height:30px;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, all the previous variants did not help.
The only thing that worked in my table was to add the **'line-height'** property to the styles of 'td', **equal to the height of the block**.

All images in table had the same width but different height and because of this the height of all 'td' was vary after yahoo 'height-to-min-height' transform.
So make the parent block have the same height for different images i put "line-height" to style. The height of the image does not exceed the parent block height.

```
<td style="height: 55px; line-height: 55px; vertical-align: middle">
<img style="width:32px,height: auto;> <span>bla</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried giving it a max height of 55 or 56px? If you do that the height should have no where else to go forcing it to be what you want it to be. Alternatively you could set the height with JS (if it is supported).

```
max-height:56px
```

with js:

```
document.getElementById('div_id').style.height = '55px';
```

Comment: I already tried max-height and it still gets transformed into min-height by both yahoo and gmail. I am trying to avoid js in my email templates if possible.

Comment: How can you use JS in emails?