# yahoo mail converts img height to min-height

Tags: css, email, yahoo-mail

Images are distorted in Yahoo Mail as it, for some reason, chooses to convert height into min-height.

I've done as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711165/subscriber-email-gmail-is-converting-height-to-min-height) but that does not help. Neither does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708089/yahoo-transforms-height-into-min-height).

This is the code for the img tag.

```
max-width:100%;height:auto;display:block;margin:20px auto;
```

And this is what Yahoo decides to do according to Firebug:

```
element {
max-width: 100%;
min-height: auto;
display: block;
margin: 20px auto;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Ehm, since `height:auto` is the default and `min-height:auto` doesn't do anything, is this really a problem?

Comment: @Ehm This is standard css for responsive images and yes it will get distorted if height:auto is not there. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217355/automatically-resize-images-with-browser-size-using-css